# SOR program not converging (FORTRAN to C conversion)

Tags: c, fortran

We're trying to convert a FORTRAN program to C. It's a SOR implementation, it's supposed to converge at around 200 iterations, but the C code not working. It goes "weird" at around the 100th iteration (it starts to converge really slowly).

Here's the original code:

```
PROGRAM Main

! ***  Solution of Laplace's Equation.
! ***
! ***  Uxx + Uyy = 0
! ***  0 <= x <= pi, 0 <= y <= pi
! ***  U(x,pi) = sin(x), U(x,0) = U(0,y) = U(pi,y) = 0
! ***
! ***  then U(x,y) = (sinh(y)*sin(x)) / sinh(pi)
! ***
! ***  Should converge with
! ***            tol = 0.001 and M = 20  in  42 iterations.
! ***   and with tol = 0.001 and M = 100 in 198 iterations.
! *** 

  INTEGER M
  PARAMETER (M   = 100)

  REAL*8   PI
  REAL*8   DATAN
  REAL*8   unew(0:M+1,0:M+1), uold(0:M+1,0:M+1)
  REAL*8   solution(0:M+1,0:M+1)
  REAL*8   omega, tol, h
  INTEGER  i, j, iters

  PI = 4.0D0*DATAN(1.0D0)

  h = PI/FLOAT(M+1)

  DO i=0,M+1
     uold(i,M+1) = SIN(FLOAT(i)*h)
  END DO

  DO i=0,M+1
     DO j=0,M
        uold(i,j) = FLOAT(j)*h*uold(i,M+1)
     END DO
  END DO

  DO i=0,M+1
     DO j=0,M+1
        solution(i,j) = SINH(FLOAT(j)*h)*SIN(FLOAT(i)*h)/SINH(PI)
     END DO
  END DO

  omega = 2.0/(1.0+SIN(PI/FLOAT(M+1)))
  tol   = 0.001

  CALL SOR (unew, uold, solution, omega, tol, m, iters)

  PRINT *, " "
  PRINT *, " Omega = ", omega
  PRINT *, " It took ", iters, " iterations."

  STOP
END PROGRAM Main


REAL*8 FUNCTION ComputeError (solution, u, m, iters)

  INTEGER m, iters
  REAL*8  u(0:m+1,0:m+1)
  REAL*8  solution(0:m+1,0:m+1)

! *** Local variables

  REAL*8  error
  INTEGER i, j

  error = 0.0

  DO j=1,m
     DO i=1,m
        error = MAX(error, ABS(solution(i,j)-u(i,j)))
     END DO
  END DO

  PRINT *, "On iteration ", iters, " error = ", error

  ComputeError = error

  RETURN
END FUNCTION ComputeError

SUBROUTINE SOR (unew, uold, solution, omega, tol, m, iters)

  INTEGER m, iters
  REAL*8  unew(0:m+1,0:m+1), uold(0:m+1,0:m+1)
  REAL*8  solution(0:m+1,0:m+1)
  REAL*8  omega, tol

! *** Local variables

  REAL*8  error
  INTEGER i, j

! *** External function.

  REAL*8   ComputeError
  EXTERNAL ComputeError

! *** Copy bonudary conditions.

  DO i=0,m+1
!     print *,i
     unew(i,m+1) = uold(i,m+1)
     unew(m+1,i) = uold(m+1,i)
     unew(i,  0) = uold(i,  0)
     unew(0,  i) = uold(0,  i)
  END DO

! *** Do SOR until 'tol' satisfied.

  iters = 0
  error = ComputeError (solution, uold, m, iters)

  DO WHILE (error .GE. tol)

! *** Do one iteration of SOR

     DO j=1,m
        DO i=1,m
           unew(i,j) = uold(i,j) + 0.25*omega* &
                (unew(i-1,j) + unew(i,j-1) + &
                uold(i+1,j) + uold(i,j+1) - &
                4.0*uold(i,j))
        END DO
     END DO

! *** Copy new to old.

     DO j=1,m
        DO i=1,m
           uold(i,j) = unew(i,j)
        END DO
     END DO

! *** Check error every 20 iterations.

     iters = iters + 1

     IF (MOD(iters,2) .EQ. 0) THEN
        error = ComputeError (solution, uold, m, iters)
     END IF

  END DO

  RETURN
END SUBROUTINE SOR
```

And here's what we've got in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define M 100

double compute_error(double solution[][M + 2], double u[][M + 2], const int m, const int iters);
void sor(double unew[][M + 2], double uold[][M + 2], double solution[][M + 2], double omega, double tol, int m, int iters);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

/*  
    Solution of Laplace's Equation.
    ==============================
    ! ***
    ! ***  Uxx + Uyy = 0
    ! ***  0 <= x <= pi, 0 <= y <= pi
    ! ***  U(x,pi) = sin(x), U(x,0) = U(0,y) = U(pi,y) = 0
    ! ***
    ! ***  then U(x,y) = (sinh(y)*sin(x)) / sinh(pi)
    ! ***
    ! ***  Should converge with
    ! ***            tol = 0.001 and M = 20  in  42 iterations.
    ! ***   and with tol = 0.001 and M = 100 in 198 iterations. 

*/

    double pi;

    double unew[M + 2][M + 2];
    double solution[M + 2][M + 2];

    double uold[M + 2][M + 2];

    double omega, tol, h;

    int i, j, iters;

    // Initialization
    for(i = 0; i <= M + 1; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= M + 1; ++j)
        {
            unew[i][j] = 0;
            uold[i][j] = 0;
            solution[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    pi = 4.0 * atan(1.0);

    h = pi / (M + 2);

    for(i = 0; i <= M + 1; ++i)
    {
        uold[i][M + 1] = sin(i * h);
    }

    for(i = 0; i <= M + 1; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= M; ++j)
        {
            uold[i][j] = j * h * uold[i][M + 1];
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i <= M + 1; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= M + 1; ++j)
        {
            solution[i][j] = sinh(j * h) * sin(i * h) / sinh(pi);
        }
    }

    omega = 2.0 / ( 1.0 + sin(pi / (M + 1)) );
    printf("omega = %.10f\n", omega);
    tol = 0.001;

    sor(unew, uold, solution, omega, tol, M, iters);

    printf(" \n");
    printf(" Omega = %f\n", omega);
    printf(" It took %d iterations.\n", iters);

    return 0;
}

double compute_error(double solution[][M + 2], double u[][M + 2], const int m, const int iters)
{
    double error = 0.0;
    int i, j;

    for(j = 1; j <= m; ++j)
    {
        for(i = 1; i <= m; ++i)
        {

            if(error >= fabs(solution[i][j] - u[i][j]))
                error = error;
            else
                error = fabs(solution[i][j] - u[i][j]);

        }
    }

    printf("On iteration %d error = %f\n", iters, error);

    return error;
}

void sor(double unew[][M + 2], double uold[][M + 2], double solution[][M + 2], const double omega, double tol, int m, int iters)
{
    double error;
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i <= m + 1; ++i)
    {
        unew[i][m + 1] = uold[i][m + 1];
        unew[m + 1][i] = uold[m + 1][i];
        unew[i][0] = uold[i][0];
        unew[0][i] = uold[0][i];
    }

    iters = 0;
    error = compute_error(solution, uold, m, iters);

    while(error >= tol)
    {


        for(j = 1; j <= m; ++j)
        {
            for(i = 1; i <= m; ++i)
            { 
                unew[i][j] = uold[i][j] + 0.25 * omega *
                                 (unew[i - 1][j] + unew[i][j - 1] +
                                 uold[i + 1][j] + uold[i][j + 1] -
                                 4.0 * uold[i][j]);     

            }
        }

        for(j = 1; j <= m; ++j)
        {
            for(i = 1; i <= m; ++i)
            { 
                uold[i][j] = unew[i][j];
            }
        }

        iters += 1;

        if(iters % 2 == 0)
        {
            error = compute_error(solution, uold, m, iters);
        }
    }
}
```

We suspect that it might be related to precision.

Comment: Probably not the immediate problem, but you have a problem with `iters`, which you're passing by value but which looks like it should be passed by reference (i.e. as a pointer in C). Note that gcc generates a warning for this - make sure you're compiling with `-Wall`.

Comment: Why do you convert a Fortran code for such a simple classical problem? There are dozens C implementations.

Comment: @VladimirF It's extra to some class' exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with `iters`, which you're passing by value but which looks like it should be passed by reference (i.e. as a pointer in C). (Note that gcc generates a warning for this - make sure you're compiling with `-Wall` to catch problems like this.)

It also looks like you mistranslated this line:

```
h = pi / (M + 1);
```

and it should most likely be:

```
h = pi / (M + 2);
```

With this change I get convergence after 196 iterations:

```
...
On iteration 192 error = 0.001293
On iteration 194 error = 0.001104
On iteration 196 error = 0.000930

 Omega = 1.939676
 It took 196 iterations.
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54efffc8a0ea121f) (this also includes fixes for the `iters` bug).

Of course there may be other bugs still to be fixed...

Comment: @VladimirF: OK - it still didn't converge after the `iters` fix alone, but fixing the `h` calculation too seemed to nail it.

Comment: Actually, it depends how you measure the convergence. Because here you measure it with regards to the true solution, it actually didn't converge before. It actually converged to a wrong solution and some methods of measuring the convergence would show it as converging too.